# Attempting to connect a simple memory chip to a computer

Tags: interface, hardware, chip-design

not too long ago a friend jokingly bought me this simple toy which basically consists of a "push-me button" that creates a laughter sound when pushed.
[How the hardware looks](http://s9.postimg.org/bws34x3tr/159511e2_5d1b_4454_91d1_8d40027746a9.jpg)
I pulled the speaker out and was wondering how one would be able to access the memory chip which contains the sound, and change it to something else.

So yes, basically, I would like to know how I would be able to connect the chip to the computer, and edit the file which is contained in the chip.

It is important to note that I'm doing this purely out of curiosity in regards to the concept (connecting this random hardware to my pc and how this thing works), so the explanation may be as general as you`d like (I would love to be able to access this specific chip regardless though).

P.S.
I would greatly appreciate if anyone could also direct me to a source of information regarding the subject at hand, as this chip got me very excited about the whole hardware/software interface thing =D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some of those toy inserts that you can record a greeting onto using the built in microphone.  Most of the super cheap toy voices are mask programmed so they are ready to speak out of the wafer fab, there are a limited number of messages and the volumes are high.  Also look up ISD chips or similar to record and play your own voices.  A friend once made a PCB that has a 14pin PIC and a serial EEPROM that could play 16 seconds of pre programmed recorder waveform. I'm sure one could do better these days.  Also look for "dipsy altera antti FPGA".

Answer (score 1):

It’s a simple battery Powered electronic toy. Here what they did mean they used one chip (where a few bytes of memory and audio amp) which is responsible for producing the laughing sound whenever you push the button.

And also that laughing sound is stored in digital form in the few bytes of memory.  Here the chip is glued(invisible). So you can't see the chip.

Basically if you want to connect any device to computer mean, you must have any of communication ports (Like USB, Ethernet, UART). Here nothing seems. 
          So, you can’t connect this device to computer unless you are the manufacturer(they probably have some special hardware to communicate with PC like converter)